# What is the name for a person who rents equipment to others

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word or two-word phrase for someone who rents their equipment to others. For example: if person A wants to rent a boat from person B, A is a renter but what is B called?

Comment: It is a **lessor** (the one who owns) - **lessee** (tenant, the one who pays) relationship: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renting. "Renter" is ambiguous and can actually work for both parties (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/renter).

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renter Both the parties can be considered "renters".

Comment: @MorganFR Can you expand it and post an answer? :)

Comment: In the case of boats, A is the *charterer* and B is the *owner* (or agent). I think owner is what you are looking for.

Comment: @PhilSweet The problem with "owner" is that it's not specific enough. For instance if you say "I'm the owner of a boat", it doesn't give us any reason to think you are renting a boat, you have to state something like "I am the owner of that boat and I'm renting it".

Comment: Thank you for your tips! However, I sort of feel lessor is a very uncommon word. This might only be because I am not a native English speaker. I'm going to use the phrase on a website and if it isn't a well known word users might easily miss vital features. Can you expect the average English speaker to know what lessor means?

Comment: @NVZ I would vote up that answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth While I did suggest what "renter" means, I actually do not have an answer to the OP's question. If you can, do post an answer. I'll upvote it. You may use all the info in these comments. :)

Comment: Isn't the answer 'renter'?

Comment: @DJClayworth I want something that is specifically the lessor to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: I don't think there's a well-established term for the *person*.  In the US, though, the place where you go to rent things is a "rental shop" or "rental agency".

Comment: Word requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research. [(more¹)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [(more²)](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) [(more³)](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3226/14073)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Lessor" is a legal term that means the owner of a piece of real estate (house, land) that is being leased.  I have never heard it used to describe a person who is the owner of rental car or boat. I think you have to say "boat owner" and make it clear from context that the owner is renting out the boat to someone. i think the average person understands the word "renter" to mean a person who is renting something from someone else.

Comment: From your text I realize that "rent out" is a proper phrasing. So could I correctly have a button which says "Begin renting out [your equipment]"?

Comment: @SiXoS - Yes, you could. (FYI I would suggest waiting more than 10 minutes before selecting an answer deserving of the tick - you can only select one of these per question, and you might get better answers coming along later. You can, however, click the upvote on every answer that is useful to you.)

Comment: "I have never heard it used ..." Where?

Answer (score 2):

I've lived in two different countries India and USA. In India, it was "land owner" and "tenant". So, this would have been like "boat owner" and "tenant"/"renter". But, in the US, the terms used are more like "lessor" and "Lessee".

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is specifically about renting, not leasing, and equipment such boats, not land or buildings, etc…

In England typically, the two parties would be referred to as the "owner" and the "hirer" or less commonly, "renter"